Can I keep the handle open for the whole program lifetime
I have a class for my Windows application which controls the panel brightness.
        h = CreateFile(displayName,
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            0, NULL);

Can I keep it open for long time (as long as app is active), or maybe I should close it and open only when required?

I'd say it depends on the flavour of file. You use CreateFile to open serial ports for example, but leaving those open when not used isn't always a good idea since other programs might want to access the same port.

You can leave a file handle open as long as you want. There is absolutely no need to close and reopen when required.
That's typically what applications like MS Word do, the .docx (or whatever) file HANDLE stays open as as long as the user hasn't closed the document.
This can be very useful when CreateFile is used with the dwShareMode parameter other than 0, for example to prevent other applications from writing into the file or deleting it while it is open.

Thank you. As it is not real file (basically it is used as a handle for IOCTL) other applications should be able to open  and use it.

With the dwShareMode parameter set to 0, other applications are able to open and use it. Just try it, there shouldn't be any issues.
